# How to use "Process Document From File" operator of RapidMiner in Java Code

Tags: rapidminer

I have just started using rapid miner for text classification. I have created a process in which i used "Process Document from Files" operator for tf-idf conversion. I want to ask how to use this operator in Java code ? I search on internet but all are using the already created process or word list generated from documents ? I want to start it from scratch i.e.

1 ) Process Documents From File

1.1) Tokenization

1.2) Filtering

1.3) Stemming

1.4) N-Gram

2) Validation

2.1) Training (K-NN)

2.2) Apply Model

Answer (score 1):

May be source code and image below can help You:

```
String              processDefinitionFileName   = "/home/maximk/.RapidMiner5/repositories/Local Repository/processes/processOpenCSV.rmp";
File                processDefinition           = new File( processDefinitionFileName );
Process             readCSV                     = new Process( processDefinition );
File                csvFile                     = new File( "/home/maximk/test.cvs" );
IOObject            inObject                    = new SimpleFileObject( csvFile );
IOContainer         inParameters                = new IOContainer( inObject );
IOContainer         outParameters               = readCSV.run( inParameters );
SimpleExampleSet    resultDataSet               = (SimpleExampleSet) outParameters.getElementAt( 0 );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx for passing through, I have found very less dev help about rapidminer on internet, Is there any way around to convert an arff file generated in weka into rapidminer's exampleset ? I am not really a rapidminer user but find out KNN in rapidminer is performing better than KNN in weka which is why i am trying to figure out a way to convert data from weka format into rapidminer's format. I am looking into options you provided and used SimpleFileObject for the purpose i intended but its not parsing it into rapidminer's exampleset..

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with this problem. I did try RapidMiner few months ago for some personal reason and I don't have any experience with weka at all...

Comment: The Read ARFF operator is your friend here. But cross-posting your question on several sites is not considered good netiquette :)